# Is this really the Saturn V computer only, or are there other systems here as well?

Tags: nasa, history, saturn-v, flight-computer

The BBC News article [Apollo in 50 Numbers; The Technology](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20190704-apollo-in-50-numbers-the-technology) shows an image of the Saturn V's computer along with the caption:

> The Saturn V's computer was probably the largest computer ever blasted into orbit (Credit: Nasa)

**Question:** I see a large number of individual boxes along the inside of this ring, and a large "cable harness" above providing interconnection between each box. Is all of this just the computer itself, or are there several related system present.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That ring is the "instrument unit" (IU).  Here's a picture of the component layout.

[image]

There is more there than a computer, but it's mostly dedicated to guidance, navigation, and control.  There's a hugely detailed fact sheet [here](https://history.msfc.nasa.gov/saturn_apollo/documents/Instrument_Unit.pdf). It lists the systems of the IU as

[image]

A more detailed layout (same source as first picture).

[image]

Image [source](https://www.apollomaniacs.com/apollo/sv_iue.htm)

Comment: fyi I've just asked [What are these white cylindrical objects pointed in different directions in this photo of the Saturn V instrument unit?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37142/12102)

Comment: new video [Apollo's Forgotten Computer - The LVDC](https://youtu.be/p12CinjFh1I) which links to [NASA TN D-5869; Description and Performance of the Saturn Launch Vehicle's Navigation, Guidance, and Control System](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19700023342.pdf) interesting dynamics are discussed, and there are some beautiful photos at various points in the video.

Comment: Here's a [pretty cool video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mMK6iSZsAs) examining the instrument ring. It features a museum display of a mock ring fitted out like the real thing including (I think) a mix of surplus artifacts and reproductions. The neat thing about this video is explanations by a docent who is a former engineer having worked on the real thing during the Apollo program. Anyway, the IU includes all sorts of stuff besides a computer, including batteries, sensors, radios, and thermal management equipment (a sublimation unit).