# What are these white cylindrical objects pointed in different directions in this photo of the Saturn V instrument unit?

Tags: identify-this-object, saturn-v

The BBC News article [Apollo in 50 Numbers; The Technology](http://www.bbc.com/future/story/20190704-apollo-in-50-numbers-the-technology) shows an image of the Saturn V's computer along with the caption:

> The Saturn V's computer was probably the largest computer ever blasted into orbit (Credit: Nasa)

According to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37141/12102) we should really call this the Saturn V Instrument Unit.

I noticed three white cylinders pointed in different directions, each with a flat base. They remind me of helical antennas (with a plastic cover) that you would point at a satellite, but I don't know what those would be doing in this setting.

**Question:** What are these white cylindrical objects pointed in different directions in this photo of the Saturn V instrument unit?

[image] [image]

[image: Saturn V Instrument Unit]

Comment: They don't seem to be part of the IU itself.  The left pair seem to be on the manufacturing floor; the right one is on the green test stand on which the IU is mounted.  They do not match anything on the diagrams of the IU.  They seem to be related to the manufacturing or testing of the IU.  Considering that the IU had radio telemetry that needed to be tested, your helical antenna hypothesis is a good guess.

Comment: Using the detailed component locator picture in the answer to the other question, we can start from the umbilical (visible at the right of the photo) and move clockwise around the ring slightly less than 90 degrees. There are two rectangular TM (telemetry) antennas shown there, which are likely the two yellow covers/fairings. Based on that, and the fact that the white cylinder has a cord running out of it, I'd also agree that they are test antennas.  The next antenna around (no fairing) is one of the C-band antennas, and I see what looks like a waveguide below it in the picture.