# Why is the Deep Space Network now testing an asteroid redirection mission that hasn't launched yet?

Tags: deep-space-network, asteroid-redirect-mission, planetary-defense, dart

The [Double Asteroid Redirection Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Asteroid_Redirection_Test) is a planned demonstration of the ability of a spacecraft to impact into and redirect the path of an asteroid.  The test is part of plans to develop a system to defend the Earth from asteroids, comets, and other hazards.

[DSN Now](https://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html) shows the mission being tested (see snapshot below), even though it isn't even planned to be launched until November 2021.  **What is this test doing right now?**  (Reputable sources please, not speculation.)

[image: DART on DSN]

Comment: different but related: [How does one test Ground Segment communications with, and “downlink” data from a spacecraft that's still on the ground?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46371) and [Was Dart antenna tested using a DSN antenna located in Australia?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/50141) (both currently unanswered)