# C-band radar in Saturn instrument unit?

Tags: saturn-v

In an answer to the recent [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/37140/is-this-really-the-saturn-v-computer-only-or-are-there-other-systems-here-as-we) there was this image:

[image]

What about 8. C-band radar? Is it an active radar unit (rocket to ground) or a radar transponder (ground to rocket) only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a transponder (really two of them).  From the [fact sheet](https://history.msfc.nasa.gov/saturn_apollo/documents/Instrument_Unit.pdf)

> Two C-band transponders are employed to provide tracking
>   capabilities...