# What do these three historical IBM staff at NASA insignias designate?

Tags: nasa, apollo-program, identify-this-object, software, insignia

The question [Where are these historical IBM + Apollo related locations within NASA? What do these computers do?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37637/12102) shows four images. Three of them show different IBM insignias on shirts of IBM staff.

**Question:** What do these three historical IBM staff at NASA insignias designate?

[image] [image] [image]

The second image (IBM IU) relates to [this accepted answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37141/12102).

Comment: The only logo I was able to find information on was the right one, which was their current logo at that time. Most likely the others were unofficial logos created for some reason that no one at that time thought would be relevant.

Comment: @BigMoneySeth thanks for looking into it and comparing to their official logo. Combining that with "IU" likely referring to the Saturn V's "Instrument Unit" (from the link I included as well as in [this caption](https://newsroom.ibm.com/apollo-image-gallery#gallery_gallery_0:21210) found in [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/37647/12102) perhaps this is enough for an answer?

Comment: Maybe but doesn't really describe what the logo's mean. Honestly I think its something simple like IBM wanted their logo easily seen in the firing room so I gave them those coats and the team in Alabama that built the IU wanted something to show off and say they worked on that. The first one baffles me sense I can't find that one anywhere else.

Comment: @SCLASethKurkowski I just ran across another IBM attire sighting https://i.stack.imgur.com/LljmV.jpg found [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/pictures/ibm-and-univac-in-the-apollo-program/4/)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that one before. That's the standard logo on the back. Not sure what the blue coat means. Might just be from a different maker that used blue. I'm gonna put all these photos into a folder and see if I find someone that might know. Maybe if I ever run into an old IBMer.